# Understanding ZF2 event system:

Tags: events, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

As in the tutorial "[MVC + Events + Modules: the new architecture of ZF2](https://speakerdeck.com/ezimuel/mvc-plus-events-plus-modules-the-new-architecture-of-zf2)" by Enrico Zimuel shown, the basic ZF2 MVC events structure looks like this:

[image: ZF2-MVC-flow-events]

[ZF MVC Auth](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-mvc-auth) extends the adds the basic MVC flow, adding four events to it (`EVENT_AUTHENTICATION`, `EVENT_AUTHENTICATION_POST`, `EVENT_AUTHORIZATION`, `EVENT_AUTHORIZATION_POST`).

Now I'm reading the Apigility "[Advanced Authentication and Authorization](https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/advanced)" documentation, that says:

> In order to achieve integration to the ZF2 MVC lifecycle for authentication, `zf-mvc-auth` wires in 4 listeners that then propagate their own events. Each of these listeners are registered within the event `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE` at different priorities.

Two point are unclear for me:

- "Each of these listeners are registered *within the event* `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE`" -- "Nested events"? What does this mean?
- "*within the event* `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE` *at different priorities*" -- Is the events priorities hierarchy "nested" / not straight-line? Is it multidimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would attach listeners *to* or *on* events; these listeners would be ordered by their *priority*.

When the event is triggered (say event `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE`) the listeners that are registered would execute one-by-one, starting with the listener with the highest priority through to the lowest.

"Nested events" or "propagate their own events" would be where one of these listeners *triggers* another event. An example of this is [the listener for rendering, `\Zend\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy::render()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php#L83), where `MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR` is triggered when a rendering error occurs.